# JMeter et Latency of the last Request

Tags: jmeter, benchmarking, jmeter-plugins, latency, jmeter-5.0

Is there any way to get the latency (i.e. duration) of the last request? I need this, because I want to wait e.g. `10 seconds - duration-of-last-request` seconds. But for this I need the time taken by the last sampler/http request. How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), the relevant code would be something like:

```
sleep 10000L - prev.getTime()
```

where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for comprehensive information on all methods/fields and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for other useful [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)